# Erro no mongodb: E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: mongodb

Estou tentando utilizar o mongodb pela primeira vez e fiz a instalação usando macports após isso.

Em um terminal executo o mongod.
Em outro executo o comando mongo.

no terminal do mongo eu tento executar o comando de import mas não consigo, da o seguinte erro ja citado no titulo da pergunta.

> E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

meu servidor esta subindo com a seguinte mensagem:

```
2015-11-14T23:33:09.540-0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-11-14T23:33:09.541-0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-11-14T23:33:09.581-0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-11-14T23:33:09.581-0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-11-14T23:33:09.628-0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-11-14T23:33:09.628-0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-11-14T23:33:09.628-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1302 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MacBookPro-HeltonWebDeveloper.local
2015-11-14T23:33:09.628-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin MacBookPro-HeltonWebDeveloper.local 15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Wed Aug 26 16:57:32 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.1.106~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_59
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-11-14T23:33:09.629-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-11-14T23:33:09.999-0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-11-14T23:33:10.011-0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-11-14T23:33:10.011-0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-11-14T23:33:10.011-0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-11-14T23:33:10.107-0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-11-14T23:33:10.107-0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-11-14T23:33:10.107-0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-11-14T23:33:10.108-0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-11-14T23:33:10.108-0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-11-14T23:33:10.108-0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Comment: Parece erro de sintaxe, que comando você está usando exatamente? Lembrando que você deve usar `mongoimport` diretamente em seu terminal e não dentro dentro do shell do comando `mongo`.

Comment: @OlimonF. sim exatamente, erro de iniciante mas eu ja fiz uma pesquisa durante umas 3 horas e sei que precisava executar em outro terminal mas nao funcionou consegue me auxiliar com outra orientação.

Comment: que comando está executando? checou no JSLint se seu JSON é valido? @heltonss

Comment: Sim tudo tranquilo... atualizei a questao com a mensagem do servidor mongod.

Answer (score 0):

O log do servidor que você postou não parece ter nada a ver com o erro original. O log provavelmente indica que há outro mongodb ativo na mesma porta. Ou você escolhe outra porta, ou usa o mongo que está ativo, ou termina-o e execute o novo.

Passado este problema, tente novamente o comando que falhou.